# PHP Documentation on strings warning

Tags: php, string

There is a part in the PHP documentation of [strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) that doesn't make sense to me:

> Non-integer types are converted to integer.

This is under the heading of

> String access and modification by character

Can anyone give an example of what this means in a piece of source code?

Comment: `$string = 'ABC'; $string[2.5] = 'D'; echo $string;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referring to the fact that you can access characters of strings by the position.  So:

```
$string = 'Example';
echo $string[2]; // a
```

Since `non-integer types are converted to integer`, that means that the indexes are type-casted to integers:

```
$string = 'Example';
$string['a'] = $string[(int) 'a'] = $string[0] = 'E';
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that if you try to access a character in that string with a non-integer value, it will have cast it to an integer, like this

```
$str="foo bar";
echo $str[1]; //outputs 'o'
echo $str[4.5]; //outputs 'b'
echo $str["A"]; //casts to zero, outputs 'f'
```

The second one will throw

```
PHP Notice:  String offset cast occured in program.php on line 4
```

and the last one will throw

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'A' in program.php on line 5
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/IGLAsO) is a demo